Why has the listing and visibility of questions changed?
The "Questions" link in the sidebar no longer lists All Questions, along with their authors but "Newest Questions" without their original authors, but the most recent editors.
Moreover, some questions with answers have simply disappeared from even the Top Questions page without comment, taking upvoted answers along with them, and affecting reputation. For example, I can find no link to the disappeared "sex worker" question asked this morning. I found it in my browser history marked as spam or offensive. Are we now so prudish that such things can't be mentioned? I saw no evidence of spam, but didn't look at the user's profile (now also disappeared). I thought the question and the answer (mine, and upvoted) was relevant to academia as an example of improper student-professor relationships. How is it better that it isn't discussable?
I'm finding both of these upsetting. Can they be justified? Things shouldn't disappear here so readily. Or is it a bug recently introduced?
Even this question didn't immediately appear in Meta!!!

About the issue from the title: "Newest Questions" tab showing last active user instead of the asker (on [meta.se]).

Note that this seems to be resolved by Dec. 11, 2024


The "Questions" link in the sidebar no longer lists All Questions, along with their authors but "Newest Questions" without their original authors, but the most recent editors...Even this question didn't immediately appear in Meta!!!

We as Academia.SE have no control over such things. You should ask on the main meta. As noted in the comments, the former has already been asked (no response yet). For the latter, I suspect it's just a routine networking issue with SE's hardware.

Are we now so prudish that such things can't be mentioned? ... How is it better that it isn't discussable?

Fear not, this was not deleted because sex work is a taboo subject. This should be clear because this question is also about sex work (indeed, it's very similar to the one you linked, maybe even a duplicate), and it was not deleted, but is still open and is in fact one of our most famous questions.

some questions with answers have simply disappeared

I'm not sure which "questions" you refer to. OPs can delete their question at any time if there are no upvoted answers (so if you answer and they delete before you are upvoted, that is allowed under SE's policies. You can raise a flag asking the mods to undelete, but we would override SE policy only on an exceptional basis). Further, closed questions with no upvoted answers are automatically deleted after a week or two. Again, this is SE policy; it may or may not be optimal, but SE-wide policies are not something we can change.
For the rest of this answer, I will address only the linked question. This question was closed by community vote. I admit I am not sure why the community gave "out of scope" as the close reason; I think closing it as a duplicate would have made much more sense. But either way, the question was correctly closed by community vote.
The closed question was then deleted by a moderator. This is pretty rare, but it happens. We don't generally comment on specific examples for privacy reasons. But one of the most common reasons why we delete a post is "trolling": we sometimes have reason to believe that the OP is setting us up by posing a fictitious but inflammatory question, for the purpose of laughing at us when we collectively waste hundreds of hours engaging with the post. This is an abuse of the community's goodwill, and so moderators will delete the posts and banish the users. Like I said, this happens pretty rarely, but it's important that we quickly delete such posts so that the user isn't rewarded for their efforts.
I am sorry that you spent time writing an answer that was deleted and that your reputation was affected. However, please remember that, as discussed here, users really should not answer questions that deserve to be closed. Some of the other stacks are really strict about this, even suspending users who answer manifestly close-worthy questions. We are not so strict here (in fact, my ratio of answers-on-closed-questions is nearly as high as yours), but it's an at-your-own-risk kind of thing. Once a question is closed, moderators have wide discretion to delete (either on their own initiative, or in response to requests). We usually don't delete if there are upvoted answers, but sometimes we do. Helping users to avoid this frustration is one of the reasons that the guidance exists, and so users who habitually ignore the guidance should expect to occasionally encounter the frustration.
